# Home screen updates do not show changes to question

Tags: bug, live-refresh

After clicking the "n questions with new activity" box on my site's home page, an old question will be brought to the top with old information. The last active user, timestamp, and answer count do not reflect any changes that caused the question to show activity.

For example, in the below screenshot is after clicking update:

[image]

And then after reloading the page:

[image]